# Javascript function not making parmanent changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am calling a javascript function by `onsubmit` event, but when  click on submit button changes happen only for a second.

```
<body>
    <p id="demo"> hello </p>
    <form id="form" onsubmit ="change()">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        function change(){document.getElementById("demo").style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById("form").style.display="block";}
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to make permanent changes after calling the function.

Comment: Is the page perhaps reloading as a result of submitting the form?

Comment: `onsubmit ="return change()">` and `function change(){document.getElementById("demo").style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById("form").style.display="block";return false;}`

Comment: oh yes this is the reason. another idiot question from me .sorry

Comment: Or `onsubmit="change(event)"` and `function change(e) {
  e.preventDefault();.....`

Comment: yeah Rayon this works but it also prevent the form to be submitted. i want to change the content after the form has been submitted.

Comment: On reload your script variables and UI state are reset. You will have to save that state somewhere, perhaps a cookie or saving some variable in your server and send it back.This is assuming you *need* to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a form will cause a page refresh.  So any changes you made to the page are lost when you reload it.

Instead of using a form with a submit button, just use a normal button.  (Since you're not actually trying to submit a form.)  Something like this:

```
<p id="demo"> hello </p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="button" onclick="change()" />
</form>
```

You can further modify it to remove the `form` entirely, which would of course require updating JavaScript and any CSS to account for the structural change.

Comment: i want to submit the form and  i want to keep changes to page even after the form is submitted. maybe i should use another php file in action attribute . but i am using $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  globle variable because then i can verify  the required field and input validation. and  show the error on the same page

Comment: @nikhil: Then you'll need to persist the changes somewhere.  Any time you end a program and re-start it (as you do with JavaScript when you reload the page), in order for that program to remember anything from the previous time it executed that information needs to be stored somewhere.  In a database, in your server-side session state, in a cookie, etc.  You can't just expect the code to remember something, you have to store your data.